# How to restrict <input type=”file” /> to get images only from phone gallery android

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, input

I am developing an IOS/Android app using cordova,php jquery and phonegap.
In android phone versions above lolypop,when uploading images/videos using `<input type=”file” />` instead of showing options like gallery and capture, it shows additional options like gallery,recent,capture, dropbox, and other cloud app storages. I want to restrict this feature and point the file input only to gallery

I want the solution exactly like below screenshot? Is there any options for restricting dropbox/other app feature?
[image]

Comment: that is how input file works. If you don't like it, you can create a dialog like that and use the camera plugin with camera or gallery option depending on the option choosen, and the use file transfer plugin to upload the image

Comment: @jcesarmobile yeah I am ok with custom dialog but if i am using the custom dialog, how can i restrict the path of the file transfer plugin only to phone gallery?

Comment: You use the camera plugin to pick/take the image https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera. If the user selects camera you use this sourceType option ```Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA```, if he picks gallery you use the sourceType ```Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY```

Comment: Thanks man I really appreciate your help

Comment: Its not working when i am browsing for a picture it still shows recent,google drive, gallery and other some temporary storages :(

Comment: try with SAVEDPHOTOALBUM, but I think it will work the same way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93353/discussion-between-geek-and-jcesarmobile).

Answer (score 1):

add this attribute to your input tag
`<input type="file" accept="image/*"/>`